# is there a way to customise the structure of a material UI component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need to add a component within the MUI component DateCalendar, i need a way to customize the structure of DateCalendar is there a way to do that ?

I tried to use slots but those were for changing the icons for example, there isn't one that i could use to add a component inside it.

here is images of how it is now vs how i want to make it:

[image]

how i want it :

[image]

Comment: How exactly do you want to customize it? Slots are most likely the right way to do it, and they are very customizable. You can override the entire Toolbar component for example, not just the icons

Comment: they seem to be used only to change already existing components that are part of dateCalendar with your own, i've for example changed the arrow icons to my own, but i want to have the month be between the arrows for example and i want to add a dropdown underneath it before the days. i've added an image for the current state of my component and another one of how i want it to be.